# pthread_mutex_lock issue in synchronization

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I have been working on code that uses pthread library in C. The code does the following:

1. Main create two threads each of which has it own thread routines(functions)
2. One thread (thread 1) generate a random number and assign it to a global variable x
3. Then the other thread (thread 2) basically prints the value of the global variable
4. This operation of generating and printing the random value of x is repeated 5 times

The expected output:

```
generator thread >> x = 5
printer thread >> x = 5
generator thread >> x = 9
printer thread >> x = 9
generator thread >> x = 7
printer thread >> x = 7
generator thread >> x = 3
printer thread >> x = 3
generator thread >> x = 2
printer thread >> x = 2
```

However, the output comes in a random order where sometimes the printer gets executed first or one of the threads gets executed multiple times before the other thread gets executed.

For example:

```
$ ./mutex.out 
generator >> x = 7
generator >> x = 10
generator >> x = 4
generator >> x = 7
generator >> x = 10
printer >> x = 7
printer >> x = 10
printer >> x = 10
printer >> x = 10
printer >> x = 10
$ ./mutex.out 
printer >> x = 0
printer >> x = 0
printer >> x = 0
printer >> x = 0
printer >> x = 0
generator >> x = 9
generator >> x = 2
generator >> x = 1
generator >> x = 3
generator >> x = 7
```

The code I have written for this problem:

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>


#define NUMTHRDS 2
pthread_t t [ NUMTHRDS];
pthread_mutex_t m1, m2; 
int x = 0; 

void *thread1(void *arg){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m2); 
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m1); 
        x = (rand() % 10) + 1; // generates a random number between 1 and 10    
        printf("generator >> x = %d\n" , x);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1); 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);
    }
}


void * thread2(void * arg){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m1); 
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m2); 
        printf("printer >> x = %d\n" , x);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2); 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{   
    srand(time(NULL));

    pthread_mutex_init(&m1, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&m2, NULL);
    
    pthread_create(&t[1], NULL, thread1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t[0], NULL, thread2, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m1);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m2);

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;

}
```

My problem is how to use mutexes correctly in order to maintain the order between these two threads without using anything else.

Comment: The main thread (main program) must wait for the end of the threads with pthread_join() otherwise the whole program may finish before the threads get any chance to do something. So call pthread_join() to wait for the end of the threads before destroying the mutexes.

Comment: The synchronization with the mutex does not guarantee the sequential execution. You should plan to use conditional variables (i.e. pthread_cond_wait/signal()) to wake up threads

Comment: This is done by pthread_exit(NULL) which I believe force the main to wait for all threads in the programs to finish

Comment: Yes but you destroy the mutex before so the threads may use destroyed mutexes...

Comment: I have moved pthread_exit(NULL) before pthread_mutex_destroy(&m1) and pthread_mutex_destroy(&m2) and the same it did not solve the issue

Comment: You're lucky the code doesn't deadlock.  If `thread1` locks `m2` and `thread2` already has `m1` but not `m2` locked, `thread1` and `thread2` will deadlock.

Comment: Please look at the other comment : you can't sequentialize the threads with mutex. Use condition variables instead. I am not sure that it is safe to do any pthread call after pthread _exit(). Hence I told you to use pthread_join(t[0], NULL);  pthread_join(t[1], NULL);  pthread_mutex_destroy(&m1); pthread_mutex_destroy(&m2); pthread_exit(NULL); (the latter is optional in the main thread).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to most of the answers and comments to this question I believe that mutexes are not the correct tool for maintaining the order between two threads. However, by the help of my instructor he shown me a trick that would work with such problem and the trick is by initially locking one of the critical sections ( critical section to be executed by thread 2 ) then unlock that one within the other thread ( thread 1 )

and this how the new code looks like

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>


#define NUMTHRDS 2
pthread_t t [ NUMTHRDS];
pthread_mutex_t m1, m2; 
int x = 0; 

void *thread1(void *arg){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
        x = (rand() % 10) + 1; // generates a random number between 1 and 10    
        printf("generator >> x = %d\n" , x);
        // 2- unlock the critical section of the printing thread
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);
}


void * thread2(void * arg){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m2);
        printf("printer >> x = %d\n" , x);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
}

int main(void) 
{   
    srand(time(NULL));

    pthread_mutex_init(&m1, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&m2, NULL);
    // 1- locking the critical section of the printing thread
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m2);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
        pthread_create(&t[1], NULL, thread1, NULL);
        pthread_create(&t[0], NULL, thread2, NULL);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m1);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m2);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I am not sure this could be regarded as an answer or qualifies as a trick worth remembering. Would you be able to inquire with your instructor on the following documentation on pthread mutexes ? "If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, undefined behavior results." https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_unlock

Comment: Note well that "undefined behavior results" means you can't rely on that to work.  You could, however, use *semaphores* in more or less that way.

Comment: what does PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL type means in linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_unlock , because I'm using pthread_mutex_t instead. I'm not sure whether they are the same or not because in my code I'm using pthread_mutex_t while the documentation mentions PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL type. although I agree that it is not reliable to use mutexes in such context. However, I'm must use it according to my instructor this way, and interestingly it is working somehow :).

Comment: I am also intrigued by your questions; You have to request these questions to your instructor or may be research stack-overflow for answers on them; If both approaches does not fulfill your quest for answers, please post a new question so other's might be able to answer your questions. Finally, In computer science or engineering, A program/solution which works never qualifies as an answer to any question but It is a useful way of delivering your assignment on time. A working program is a small step forward in finding the lasting program.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems at first sight:

1. The serialization of the threads do not work with the mutex
2. The call to *pthread_mutex_destroy()* before waiting for the end of the threads makes the latter probably use destroyed mutexes

Here is a proposal to serialize the threads with condition variables and to terminate properly using *pthread_join()*:

```c
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>


#define NUMTHRDS 2
pthread_t t [ NUMTHRDS];
pthread_mutex_t m1, m2; 
int x = 0; 
pthread_cond_t cond1, cond2;
int gen, prt;


void *thread1(void *arg){
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
    if (!gen) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &m1);
    }

    x = (rand() % 10) + 1; // generates a random number between 1 and 10    
    printf("generator >> x = %d\n" , x);

    gen = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);

    // Wake up printer
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m2);
    prt = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);

  }
}


void * thread2(void * arg){
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m2); 
    if (!prt) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond2, &m2);
    }
    printf("printer >> x = %d\n" , x);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2); 

    prt = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);

    // Wake up generator
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
    gen = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
  }
}

int main(void) 
{   
  srand(time(NULL));

  pthread_mutex_init(&m1, NULL);
  pthread_mutex_init(&m2, NULL);

  pthread_cond_init(&cond1, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&cond2, NULL);

  pthread_create(&t[1], NULL, thread1, NULL);
  pthread_create(&t[0], NULL, thread2, NULL);

  // Wake up generator
  printf("Waking up generator...\n");
  pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
  gen = 1;
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);

  pthread_join(t[0], NULL);
  pthread_join(t[1], NULL);

  pthread_mutex_destroy(&m1);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&m2);

  pthread_cond_destroy(&cond1);
  pthread_cond_destroy(&cond2);

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but I just wanted to explicitly say something that is implicit in other answers.

> ...how to use mutexes correctly in order to maintain the order between these two threads...

That is not the purpose of mutexes. Mutexes are the wrong tool for that.

The lowest-level tool that you can use when you want one thread to wait for another to do something is called a [*condition variable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables). In the posix threads library (pthreads), you use a `pthread_cond_t` variable, and various `pthread_cond_...(...)` functions that operate on it:

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html

---

But also note: There are well-established, higher level patterns that people usually use for solving your type of problem. E.g., Google for "blocking queue."